# define relationship between classes in protege5.0

Tags: ontology, protege, object-property

I'm building my ontology using Protege tool and I've defined my classes and individuals. 
Now, I want to add relationship between classes. However, I've read that:

> object property define relations between instances, but in OWL we can
>   use restriction to define relations between classes

Can you help with some example to understand that?

My issue:
I have `class1` and `class2` for which I need to build an "opposite Of" relation between those classes.
Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps you can follow:

(1) Create the classes `Class1` and `Class2`.

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://henrietteharmse.com/tutorial/DomainRangeExample#Class1"/>
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://henrietteharmse.com/tutorial/DomainRangeExample#Class2"/>
```

(2) Define an object property, say, `related` with domain `Class1` and range `Class2`:

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://henrietteharmse.com/tutorial/DomainRangeExample#related">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://henrietteharmse.com/tutorial/DomainRangeExample#Class1"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://henrietteharmse.com/tutorial/DomainRangeExample#Class2"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

**Explanation**
This states that if individual `a` is related to individual `b` via the object property `related` then `a` will be assumed to be of type `Class1` and `b` will be assumed to be of type `Class2`.

(3) Define another object property, say `inverseRelated`, that is the inverse of `related`:

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://henrietteharmse.com/tutorial/DomainRangeExample#inverseRelated">
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="http://henrietteharmse.com/tutorial/DomainRangeExample#related"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

**Explanation**
This states that if individual `a` is related to individual `b` via the object property `inverseRelated` then `a` will be assumed to be of type `Class2` and `b` will be assumed to be of type `Class1`.

(4) Define 2 individuals, say `individual1` and `individual2` with `individual1` to `individual2` via the `inverseRelated` object property:

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://henrietteharmse.com/tutorial/DomainRangeExample#individual1">
    <DomainRangeExample:inverseRelated rdf:resource="http://henrietteharmse.com/tutorial/DomainRangeExample#individual2"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://henrietteharmse.com/tutorial/DomainRangeExample#individual2"/>
```

(5) If you now run a reasoner over your ontology (i.e. in Protege), you will see that `individual1` is inferred to be of type `Class2` and `individual2` is of type `Class1`.

Comment: Thank you for replying,   I think this suggestion is useful but not in my case, cause I just wanted to define that relation to annotate my document (without using reasoner),as an example:  I've defines two classes "good" and "bad" , if my document has a sentence like "I'm not so good today" and after searching in my ontology (which is built via protege) but loaded to GATE  tool, I'll find 2 important tokens: "not" and "good" so the program should get from the ontology the class which is opposite of "good", and the final result is "bad"

Comment: I've  found some code but it was written in OWL2: <Class IRI="#Good"/>
<ObjectSomeValuesFrom>
<ObjectProperty IRI="#isOppositeOf"/>
<Class IRI="#Bad"/>
</ObjectSomeValuesFrom>  maybe, I need something like it, but in OWL.!

Answer (score 1):

Consider classes A and B (I'm using turtle syntax)

```
:A rdf:type owl:Class .
:B rdf:type owl:Class .
```

You can define A and B to be disjoint (a relationship between classes), meaning that if an element is one of them it cannot be in another.

```
:A owl:disjointWith :B .
```

If you query for example:

```
not B
```

You obtain class *A*.  It also works for individuals.

Comment: Thanks for replying, It's a simple solution I'll try it, but  how can I reach the opposite of "B" if I don't use query in protege, I have to find that relation via java code!

Comment: @SuznCB that's a whole new question you can post it separately.   In the meantime see this example with java code https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/DL-Queries-with-a-real-reasoner. You can still pass the query "not B" through the code.